# iOS 8 - setting the inner color of a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I am trying to make a search bar fill the full screen width and be one solid color in a rectangle shape. However, setting the 'tint color' only sets the color of the search bar border.
 How can the inner color be set too, either in Swift or directly in xCode 6? This could be done using a text field instead, but I prefer the search bar for maintainability and its extra features.

Answer (score 0):

Set an image in your search bar's `textField.background` and this should do the trick. e.g.

```
for (UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITextField")]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subView;
        textField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image"];
    }
}
```